# Anybody know how to get ahold of SAM76 source code for Linux?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, lisp

resistors.org site and foxthompson.net download links are stale/broken.

http://www.resistors.org/index.php/The_SAM76_programming_language

Every other link I've been able to track down on the 'net (mostly in old newsgroup posts) are broken.  E-mails to the respective webmasters all bounced.

I have a morbid curiosity for arcane programming languages, and SAM76 sounded really interesting to look into and mess around with.

There are quite a few lisp folks lurking on this site, so figured somebody might have a lead... as I heard SAM76 had some early redimentary functional programming ideas.

Extra credit: link to track down a copy of the SAM76 manual!

Answer (score 4):

Wayback has a copy of S76.exe for DOS and Windows

http://web.archive.org/web/20070505122813/http://www.resistors.org/index.php/The_SAM76_programming_language

http://wikivisually.com/wiki/SAM76

<strike>http://encycl.opentopia.com/term/Sam76</strike>

<strike>http://encycl.opentopia.com/term/Algorithms_in_Sam76</strike>

> ======================= F R E E W A R E =======================
>
> ```
>                         User-Supported Software
>         If you are using this program and find it to be of value
>                your $20 contribution will be appreciated.
>         A contribution of $30 will bring you the  SAM76 language
>          manual and other useful and interesting documentation.
>
>         SAM76 Inc., Box 257 RR1
>          Pennington, N.J., 08534
>           U.S.A.
>
>              Regardless of whether you make a contribution,
>            you are encouraged to copy and share this program.
> ```
>
> ### >                ---------------------------------------------------

http://web.archive.org/web/20110726163455/http://www.hypernews.org/HyperNews/get/computing/lang-list/2/2/1.html

I believe the R.E.S.I.S.T.O.R.s (have no idea what the letters
mean) was a group of kids who played with computers and
electronics in Claude Kagan's barn in Pennington, N.J. near
Princeton.  Because the developer of TRAC, Calvin Mooers,
spent the rest of his life inventing the software patent and
sued everyone in sight, Claude (whose employer, Western
Electric Laboratories was sued by Mooers) created a very
similar language called "SAM76" supposedly based on S7 and M6
"languages from Bell Labs".  I have the original tutorial
manual written and illustrated by the R.E.S.... and versions
on paper tape for the Altair and TRS-80 floppy disk.  I think
it looked more like @os@is;; but you could change all the
special characters and command names so it could be made to
look EXACTLY like TRAC.  Claude wrote some neat graphic games

### for the TRS-80 in SAM76/TRAC.

http://web.archive.org/web/20110726163335/http://www.hypernews.org/HyperNews/get/computing/lang-list/2/2/1/3.html

Yes, we RESISTORS did indeed meet in Claude's barn which was filled with old telephone and computer equipment. Claude's version of TRAC started on the PDP-8, migrated to the PDP-10, and for the legal reasons mentioned ended up as SAM-76. (FYI, SAM stands either for "Strachey and McIlroy" or "Same As Mooers". RESISTORS always stood for "Radically Emphatic Students Interested in Science, Technology, and Other Research Studies" as much as it stood for anything.

Starting when we were members of the RESISTORS, Peter Eichenberger and I wrote a PDP-10 TRAC processor and later reimplemented it for the PDP-11, eventually adding a little multi-terminal time-sharing monitor. We kept a lower profile than Western Electric (either that, or as 19 year olds we had no noticable assets) so we and Mooers stayed on cordial terms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is useful, but on [this page](http://www.resistors.org/index.php/Dave_Fox's_RESISTORS_page) there is an email adress dsf@hci.ucsd.edu which seems to be Dave Fox's one, the guy who maintained the page hosting the SAM76 file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pile of information in the old SIMTEL archives, specifically CPMUG Volume 34, which is included in the nearly 13G download [here](http://smartbasic.net/2017/11/07/simtel-cpm-user-group-files/) including example code.  You have your choice of "DSK" and "ARK" (ARC) format images.  The standard {file} utility knows what format it's in {CPMUG034.ARC: ARC archive data, dynamic LZW}  SIG/M v. 53 also has SAM76 information and you can find it [here](http://oldcomputers.dyndns.org/public/pub/cdrom/Walnut_Creek_CDROM/simtel/sigm/vols000/vol053/index.html).